# firebase realtime database query with react native endless loop

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, react-native-flatlist

The firebase RTDB looks like this:

```
users / userID / email, 
                 username, 
                 id,
                 posts/ id / id,
                             timestamp,
                             messages: String
                      / id /  id,
                             timestamp,
                             messages: String
                     / id /  id,
                             timestamp,
                             messages: String
```

So I'm trying to loop through the id under posts and retrieve all of the messages, push said messages to an array and render them with a Flatlist component.

I am simply wondering if anyone can point out what about this code makes an infinite loop? I'm at a loss.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View, Text } from 'react-native'

import firebase from 'firebase'
import "firebase/database"

interface userObjectProp {
    userCredentials: Object,
}

const YourMessages = ({userCredentials}: userObjectProp) => {

    const [messages, setMessages] = useState(Array)
    
    firebase.database().ref("users/" + userCredentials.id + "/posts").on("value", (snapshot)=> {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot)=> {
            setMessages(messages=>[...messages, childSnapshot.child("message").val()])
        })
    })
    
    const renderItem = ({item}: any)=> {
        return (
            <Text>{item}</Text>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <FlatList data={messages} renderItem={renderItem} extraData={messages}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

To answer @Dharmaraj, it is the child of this screen component: ChatScreen.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import globalStyle from '../css/globalStyle'

import Logout from '../components/Logout'
import YourMessages from '../components/chatScreen/YourMessages'
import RecievedMessages from '../components/chatScreen/RecievedMessages'
import SendText from '../components/chatScreen/SendText'

import {Props} from "../types/types"

const ChatScreen = ({route}: Props) => {

    const userObject = route.params.user

    const [input, setUserInput] = useState(String)

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Logout/>
            <View style={styles.chatWindow}>
                 <YourMessages userCredentials={userObject}/>
                <View><RecievedMessages/></View> 
            </View>
            <View style={styles.chatAndButton}>
                <TextInput onChangeText={setUserInput} value={input} style={styles.textInput} placeholder="Chat..."/>
                <SendText message={input} userCredentials={userObject} />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where are you importing `YourMessages`?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i edited to post to answer your question.